# Issues with associating subscribers to a delegate

Tags: c#

When I was reading on delegates. I decided to write a simple example as Console application which could mimic button actions.

So I create a delegate and try to subscribe two methods(OnSomethingHappened_1 and OnSomethingHappened_2) to the myButtonObj.Click event. Below shows what I did so far:

```
using System;

namespace DelegateConsoleExample
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(string foo);

    class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyButton myButtonObj = new MyButton();

            myButtonObj.Click += new MyEventHandler(OnSomethingHappened_1);
            myButtonObj.Click += new MyEventHandler(OnSomethingHappened_2);
        }

        public static void OnSomethingHappened_1(string bar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x method runs");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void OnSomethingHappened_2(string bar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("y method runs");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyButton
    {
        MyEventHandler myField;

        public event MyEventHandler Click
        {
            add { myField += value; }
            remove { myField -= value; }
        }
    }
}
```

But I couldnt figure out where I am doing wrong since I cannot invoke the event by myButtonObj.Click("foo");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly when you define a delegate as an **event** you can only invoke it from inside the class itself.
Secondly when you explicitly define add/remove for the event you have to use the backing field to invoke it.
So you may do this to call it:

```
public class MyButton
{
    MyEventHandler myField;

    public event MyEventHandler Click
    {
        add { myField += value; }
        remove { myField -= value; }
    }

    public void Invoke(string s)
    {
        myField(s);
    }
}

//and then calling it like this:
myButtonObj.Invoke("foo");
```

Comment: But only OnSomethingHappened_1 fires

Comment: Oh its because  I needed to remove Console.ReadKey(); Now works fine

Comment: @GNZ Glad you got it working. Please mark my answer as accepted then.